# Use mysql with Delphi 7

Tags: mysql, delphi

I would like to connect Delphi 7 with any version of MySql using dbExpress components, Is it possible ?

I tried to use libmysql.dll, but it showed me an error indicating that it failed to initialize the library.

Comment: Use the native Delphi 7 components for connect with MySQL is very oldfashion. My recommendation is to use Zeoslib components (http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/). It allow you develop and App using your old Delphi 7 and connect natively to MySQL (ODBC is not required)

Comment: +1 for Zeoslib. However, you still need to use libmysql.dll when using Zeos and that raises license issues. libmysql open source license is GPL, so you can't link to it unless your project is GPL compatible.

Comment: And about the error you're getting, try reinstalling the client library to see if it goes away.

Comment: Do you have the Enterprise or Architect SKU? The Pro and lower versions didn't include MySQL drivers for dbExpress and were not licensed to use them with MySQL, IIRC. (Delphi 7 is extremely old, and it's been quite a while since I used it, so my memory might be wrong.)

Comment: you can try using mORMot library - http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/03/07/Support-of-MySQL,-DB2-and-PostgreSQL  ///  and you can search for more MySQL libraries at the following links: http://torry.net/pages.php?id=1170  //  http://torry.net/pages.php?id=554 - MyDAC/UniDAC components there should provide dbx driver for mySQL